# Is there any relation between BSON storage for mongoDB and MySQL storage?

Tags: mysql, json, mongodb, storage, bson

I am working on an application where I need to make analysis that what will be the storage size of `BSON` structure, which is used by `MongoDB`, if the same data is stored which is stored in `MySQL`. Basically I am comparing `MongoDB` and `MySQL` storage. Is there any **relation** between them? or some **formula** which gives size of `BSON` storage?

Even the `MySQL` to `JSON` storage and `JSON` to `BSON` storage will also be good.

Comment: They will not be the same, that is a rather useless comparison. As for calculating BSON size, are you taking indexes into account?

Comment: There are many factors that go into disk space usage, and it also depends what exactly you are trying to estimate (just the data, or data + indexes, or overall file system usage). The best way to estimate storage for your use case would be to generate some example data and indexes and extrapolate based on that (with an added margin for error). You should ideally run some representative updates to determine the longer term efficiency of your data model as well; some update patterns tend to lead to storage fragmentation and less efficient usage.

Comment: FYI: the BSON spec is available from http://bsonspec.org/ if you want to learn more about the storage format, and the `Object.bsonsize(document)` command in the `mongo` shell will tell you the size of a BSON document in bytes.